# Broken fixed header in responsive bootstrap on scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, header

After some trial and error, I managed to get the menu to scale the way I wanted. The issue I came across is in the mobile view. Parts of the menu stay fixed and others still scroll. I can't tell where in the code I am making a mistake.

Here is my markup.

```
<header class="top-head">
      <div class="col-xs-4 pull-left"></div>
        <div class="dclogo"></div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5 pull-right eye_brow">
          <div class="pull-right">
            <a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>  Stuff<a/>
            <a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i>  Stuff</a>
          </div>

          <br/>

          <div class="pull-right sub_settings">
            <span class="bld">Stuff Stuff</span> | <a href="">Stuff Settings</a> | <a href="">Stuff</a> | <a href="">Stufft</a>
          </div>
        </div>

    </header>

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

  </div>
```

Here is my functionality.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.navbar-collapse').toggleClass('rght');
    $('.navbar-toggle').toggleClass('indexity');
  });
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 6) {

    $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    $('.navbar ').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
  } else {

    $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
  }
});

$('.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('open');
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('open');
});

$('a.page-footer__links-column-expansion-link').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('page-footer__section--expanded')
})   

//Navbar Toggle

$(".navbar-toggle").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 1) {
        $('.hdd').addClass('fixxedd');
        //$('.top-head').addClass('fixxed');
        $('.navbar-toggle').addClass('fixxedr');
        //$('.navbar-nav > li:firtst-child').addClass('blkk');
        $('.nav > li.dclogo_wht').removeClass('non');

    } else {
        $('.hdd').removeClass('fixxedd');
        //$('.top-head').removeClass('fixxed');
        $('.navbar-toggle').removeClass('fixxedr');
        //$('.navbar-nav > li:firtst-child').removeClass('blkk');
        $('.nav > li.dclogo_wht').addClass('non');
    }

});
```

Here is the jsfiddle with everything all together. 
https://jsfiddle.net/galnova/qhwnhwL1/15/

I have it almost there I just can't stop part of the header from scrolling and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Remove navbar-toggle fixxedr and navbar-fixed-top in the mobile view.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I commented the 'fixxedr' out and now everything scrolls again. I want the logo and hamburger to stay fixed there with a white background though. Any thoughts on what I am missing?

Comment: please update the jsfiddle with new code so that I can take a look.

Comment: Can I see a fiddle please

Comment: $(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 6) {

    //$('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    //$('.navbar ').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
  } else {

    $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
  }
});

Comment: I want it to be fixed though. When I comment that out it all scrolls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128203/discussion-between-riotgear-and-user3407386).

Comment: It wont let me...Its blocked where I am